# Decimal type in php

Tags: php

Does PHP have Decimal(±1.0 × 10−28 to ±7.9 × 1028) data type?

Comment: Related: Floating point numbers in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [BC Math](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) extension implements arbitrary-precision  decimal math:

```
$a = '0.1';
$b = '0.2';
echo bcadd($a, $b);     // prints 0.3
```

(From [The Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/php/))